# how can use svg shape in web design?

Tags: html, svg, inline-svg

I want use the svg code of a shape like the image full width [triangle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFYI7.png)
how can use this svg to fill the browser? here is the code of it

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g>
  <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="100%" width="100%" y="0" x="0"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="svg_1" d="m583.25,1l-582.5,404l4,-402l578.5,-2z" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#33666C"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson this is the code I exported from a tool.
`<path id="svg_1" d="m583.25,1l-582.5,404l4,-402l578.5,-2z" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#33666C"/>` this part is for that triangle, that I have problem with.

Comment: I wanna this triangle  be like the  image, imagine the image fill the whole of browser. the image in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFYI7.png

Comment: @RobertLongson It's not fill whole of the browser I think because of the `d="m583.25,1l-582.5,404l4,-402l578.5,-2z"` in path tag.
I'm beginner at svg and I don't know how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this I guess. I've added a viewBox so the shape scales.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 584 405" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g>
  <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="100%" width="100%" y="0" x="0"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path id="svg_1" d="m583.25,1l-582.5,404l4,-402l578.5,-2z" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#33666C"/>
</g>
</svg>
```